thread id/token ID generation for new emails
We have a custom app in our org that uses the apex email service to send an email notification to our external users when the customer issues need to be addressed by an onsite visit. When the external users reply to this email, this inbound email get attached to the original notification email all works fine.
When our user creates and sends a new email from this custom application, the reply/inbound email get received in SF but not attaching to the original email.
Below is the response from Salesforce developer support.
We are not getting the thread token name for custom objects, preventing us from adding it to the subject line. A custom code implementation is required to achieve this functionality. The Apex Email Service may not be configured to handle token ID generation for new emails. If the Apex code or configuration is incorrect or incomplete, it may fail to generate the token ID for new emails, leading to the issue.
I am wondering if anyone faced this issue when implementing the email function in custom application and how the thread token was managed.
Thanks for your help
SJ
